# MySQL connection issue with Pomelo game framework

Tags: mysql, node.js, pomelo

I have deployed [Pomelo](https://github.com/NetEase/pomelo) server on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu) instance.

When I run the server, it works correctly.
But after several hours later, server crashed with mysql issue.

> [2023-04-26 02:01:26.771] [ERROR] console -  Caught exception: Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 14
> at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/var/cw_server/game-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:470:15)
> at Parser.write (/var/cw_server/game-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)
> at Protocol.write (/var/cw_server/game-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
> at Socket. (/var/cw_server/game-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
> at Socket. (/var/cw_server/game-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

`*Note*: I used the same code as lordofpomelo for MySQL.`

So, I created a simple socket server that uses the same database and it works correctly.